# Does Intermediate Value Property and closed graph imply continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

This is a problem I found in the book of CAROTHERS "REAL ANALYSIS" and it states:

> If $f:\Bbb R\rightarrow\Bbb R$ has the intermediate value property and the graph  is closed show that $f$ is continous.

There is also a "HINT" but I cannot proceed furhter.Any help is realy appreciated.

Comment: What's the hint?

Comment: if $$f$$ is discontinous at $$b$$ then there is a sequense $$b_n$$ with $$b_n\to b$$ and $$f(b_n) > f(b)+\delta$$...

Comment: What do you mean by "the graph is closed"?

Comment: @Long, I mean topologicaly closed....i.e any congruent sequense of points of the graph has limit point of the graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $f$ is discontinuous at $a$. There are then two possibilities: either $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists (in $\overline{\mathbb R}$) but it is different from $f(a)$ or the limit does not exist. The first possibility cannot occur if $f$ has the intermediate value property. Suppose that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ does not exist. Then you can find two real numbers $y_0$ and $y_1$ with $y_0<y_1$ such that, for every $\delta>0$, there are $x_0,x_1\in(a-\delta,a+\delta)\cap D_f$ with $f(x_0)\leqslant y_0$ and $f(x_1)\geqslant y_1$. Since $f$ has the intermediate value property, the closure of the graph of $f$ will then contain $\{a\}\times[y_0,y_1]$. But we are supposing that the graph is closed, that is that the closure of the graph is the graph itself and a graph cannot contain a vertical line segment.

Comment: Thanks Jose! Now I get the hint too! We may also simplify your nice proof a bit like this: If $f$ is not continuous at $a$ then there is a sequence $a_n$ with $a_n\to a$ and $\epsilon>0$ such that $|f(a_n)-f(a)|>\epsilon$. We can also assume that $f(a) <\epsilon+f(a_n)$. Now take a value $m$ between $f(a)$ and $f(a)+\epsilon$ then that $f$ has the IVP means that there is sequence $b_n$ with $b_n\to a$ and $f(b_n)=m$. Now that the graph is close means that $m$ is $f(a)$, which is impossible.

Comment: By the way how do you find these real numbers $$y_0, y_1?$$

Comment: @dmtri Since $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ does not exist, $\limsup_{x\to a}f(x)>\liminf_{x\to a}f(x)$. Just take two real numbers $y_0$ and $y_1$ such that$$\liminf_{x\to a}f(x)\leqslant y_0<y_1\leqslant\limsup_{x\to a}f(x).$$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos  inequalities must be strict, otherwise, it's wrong